# Why is onDataChange starts at the end?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The onDataChange method is always executed last, so the centuries list in other methods is empty. How to make `onDataChange` start before `onCreateView`? Offer your own solutions for the correct filling of the list. No idea how to implement it. Thank you in advance!

## Fragment code

Here I am filling the centuries list with data from firebase but for some reason it does not load as it should

```
public class HomeStartFragment extends Fragment implements recyclerInterface {
    private Context context;
    private View view;
    private RecyclerView rv;

    private List<Century> centuries;
    private List<Article> articles;
    private CenturiesAdapter centuriesAdapter;
    private ArticlesAdapter articlesAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference  mDataBaseCentury, mDataBaseArticle;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public static HomeStartFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeStartFragment fragment = new HomeStartFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("MyTaggg", "ONCREATE STARTED");
        centuries = new ArrayList<>();
        articles = new ArrayList<>();
        mDataBaseCentury = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://vitebsk-history-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference("Century");
        mDataBaseArticle = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://vitebsk-history-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference("Article");
        Log.i("MyTaggg", "ListSize in onCreate = " + centuries.size());
        getCenturiesFromDB();
        getArticlesFromDB();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    private void getCenturiesFromDB(){
        Log.i("MyTaggg", "FUNC STARTED");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Log.i("MyTaggg", "ONDATACHANGE is working");
                if(centuries.size()>0){centuries.clear();}
                for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Century century = ds.getValue(Century.class);
                    assert century !=null;
                    centuries.add(century);
                }

                Log.i("MyTaggg","ListSize in func = " + centuries.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        mDataBaseCentury.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }
    private void getArticlesFromDB(){
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(articles.size()>0){articles.clear();}

                for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Article article = ds.getValue(Article.class);
                    assert article != null;
                    articles.add(article);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        mDataBaseArticle.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.i("MyTaggg", "ONCREATEVIEW STARTED");
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.century_view, container, false);
        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recCenturyView);
        centuriesAdapter=new CenturiesAdapter(getContext(),centuries,articles,this);
        articlesAdapter = new ArticlesAdapter(getContext(),articles,this);
        rv.setAdapter(centuriesAdapter);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        Log.i("MyTaggg", "ListSize in onCreateView = " + centuries.size());
        return view;
    }

}
```

**I don't know what else to write, stackoverflow won't let me post my question.**

### Log

```
2023-06-09 20:20:50.404  1979-1979  MyTaggg       com.example.vitsebskhistory        I  ONCREATE STARTED
2023-06-09 20:20:50.466  1979-1979  MyTaggg       com.example.vitsebskhistory        I  ListSize in onCreate = 0
2023-06-09 20:20:50.466  1979-1979  MyTaggg       com.example.vitsebskhistory        I  FUNC STARTED
2023-06-09 20:20:50.488  1979-1979  MyTaggg       com.example.vitsebskhistory        I  ONCREATEVIEW STARTED
2023-06-09 20:20:50.581  1979-1979  MyTaggg       com.example.vitsebskhistory        I  ListSize in onCreateView = 0
2023-06-09 20:20:51.606  1979-1979  MyTaggg       com.example.vitsebskhistory        I  ONDATACHANGE STARTED
2023-06-09 20:20:51.611  1979-1979  MyTaggg       com.example.vitsebskhistory        I  ListSize in func = 8
```

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabase).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can't (and you shouldn't).

The Firebase database callbacks are asynchronous and complete whenever data is available.  You have no guarantees if or when that happens.  The activity is going to render its UI as soon as it can, and will not wait for anything else to complete.  You should also never attempt to block Android callbacks, since doing so will cause your application to "soft crash" with an "Application not responding" error.

If you want to block your UI until a database query completes, you should write code to add some sort of spinner or wait screen that suggests the user should wait until the data is available, the update the UI with the results of the query.